# how to add a click event for the selected table row?

Tags: jquery

I have a table (tblPrograms) whose rows are populated dynamically in JQuery function.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Programs
        </td>
        <td>
            Description
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="height: 115px; overflow: auto;">
                <table id="tblPrograms">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Name</td>
        <td>value</td>
        </tr>

        <!--<tr>
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="txt_program1" class="MyTextBox" type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="txt_value1" class="MyTextBox" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>-->
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea id="txtProgDesc" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
...
</table>
```

Here is the JQuery function:

this.Init = function()
{
    var myself = this;

```
myself.get_Service().GetAllPrograms(
    function(data){

        $('#tblPrograms tr').not(':first').not(':last').remove();
        var html='';
        for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
            var j=i+1;
            html+='<tr><td>' + j + '</td><td><input id="txt_program' + j + '" class="MyTextBox" type="text" />' + 
            '</td><td><input id="txt_value' + j + '" class="MyTextBox" /></td></tr>';                 
        }
        $('#tblPrograms tr').first().after(html);

        ...

        //Bind the values
        for(i=0; i < data.length; i++){
            var j=i+1;
            myself.BindElement("txt_program" + j, data[i].program);
            myself.BindElement("txt_value" + j, data[i].value);
        }
});

...
```

}

Now I need to achieve following tasks:
(1) If any, the first row in the table should be highlighted by default, and Description (txtProgDesc) will be updated;

(2) When I click any row in table tblPrograms, the selected row will be highlighted, other rows will be de-highlighted, and the Description will be updated accordingly.

For task (1), I tried to add following code at the end of the Init func, but it doesn’t seem working. As for the task (2), I know I should add a click event for each row, but where, when and how should I do?

```
$('#tblPrograms tr').children('tr:first').css('background-color', 'Red');
```

Comment: I would wrap the element in a span or anchor element with id or class (in case you want events that are equal for entire columns for example). Is that an option?

Comment: I only want the click event the row level

Comment: Same thing. You can define the class / id on the content when you build the table. It seems more logical to me to add a class to the content of the cells per row, than on the table rows themselves. Because the table in the end, is only a holder for the data. What you really click is the content.

Answer (score 1):

First at all:
Create a class in your CSS file to highlight the cell... Here i will it as "td-highlighted":

```
.td-highlight{ background-color: #f00; }
```

Now in yout JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tblPrograms tr:first').addClass("td-highlight"); // Here your task(1)
    // UPDATE your txtProgDesc

    $('#tblPrograms tr').live("click",function(){
        $('#tblPrograms tr').removeClass("td-highlight");
        $(this).addClass("td-highlight"); // Here your task (2)
        // UPDATE your txtProgDesc
    });
});
```

Comment: It highlighted the head of the table. I tried $('#tblPrograms tr:nth-child(2)').addClass("td-highlight"); but it is not working? And I noticed the ready gets called after init.

Comment: How do I avoid the first row of the table (column header) gets highlighted? And how do I get the column's value of highlighted row?